# Using the map after update

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I use the Pokemon map to catch more/rarer Pokemon after this new update? For example:

```
 How can I use the selector in the bottom right corner to find rarer Pokemon?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do these leaves signify anything?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272708/do-these-leaves-signify-anything), [Do certain Pokemon types appear more often in some locations?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273939/do-certain-pokemon-types-appear-more-often-in-some-locations), [Why should I “watch” a nearby pokémon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272636/why-should-i-watch-a-nearby-pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: You can learn more about how to tracking a pokémon on this great tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0of-hWhKmPM